# Post html code via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So Im using TinyMCE editor and I need to post html code created.

```
$(".saveButton").click(function () {
var url = $(this).data('url');
var HTMLCode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    data: { HTMLCode : HTMLCode },
    success: function (data) {
       //do something
    },
    error: function () {
        toastr.error('Something went wrong.');
    }
});
```

Im ofcourse getting 500 error because HTMLCode looks like this -

```
"<span class="someclass">test</span>"
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Serverside code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveHTML(string HTMLCode)
    {
        //save HTMLCode to db            
        return Json(new { retVal = "success" });           
    }
```

Comment: I highly doubt that is what is being sent and problem is more likely in your server side code. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl  I have edited question, I do not really see a problem on serverside code, maybe Im wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Webbanditten. just added `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute to posting action.